# ASP.NET MVC Routes - domain.com/Events#!/12 to domain.com/Events/12

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm updating a few sections in a website with Ajax, but now i'm trying to do something similar to what facebook does.
When i update the content of a section, the problem is that my url remains the same. If i see the facebook example:

http://www.facebook.com/guilhermegeek#!/guilhermegeek?sk=photos

This link is mapped to: http://www.facebook.com/guilhermegeek?sk=photos

I already know how to use an alternative for those who have javascript disable:  `<a onclick="javascript:updatecontent(); return false;" href="">`

But what i don't know is how to write my routes like the example of Facebook.

If i change my url to **mydomain.com/News#!/News/12**, how should i route this to **mydomain.com/News/12** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that follows the `#` (hash, pund) sign of the url is **NEVER** sent to the server. The server only sees the part before it. Only client side javascript could use and make sense of it using `window.location.hash`. So if you want to use something like this in your application you should leave the default route as is and then have some javascript parse the part following the `#` sign and perform a redirect to the corresponding url.

So you could have something like this in your page:

```
var h = window.location.hash;
if (h != null) {
    var parts = window.location.href.split('#!/');
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        window.location.replace(parts[0] + '/' + parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So i have to make the routing in cliente-side with javascript?

Comment: @Guilherme, no, you leave the default route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` on your server and you redirect with javascript.

Comment: Thank you Darin. I've solved this with your help. I had to change the window.location to window.location.replace("http://mydomain.com/" + parts[1]);